# Convert Local HTML table with Id to Excel Table using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an issue converting a single Local HTML Table in an HTML file(Contains 2 Tables) using ID to Excel Table .

I refered stackoverflow to get this code :

```
import os
import time
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


outfile= open('out.txt','wb')
rfile  = open('Report.html', encoding="utf8")
rsoup  = BeautifulSoup(rfile)
nodes  = rsoup.find('table',{'id':'test-details'}).find_all('tr')
for node in nodes:
    a = node.find('th')
    x = None
    if a != None:
        x1 = x.find('b')
        if x1 != None:
            x2 = x1.get_text().encode("utf-8")
            print (x2)
            x = x2
    y = node.find('th')
    if y != None:
        print ('y',y)
        y2  = y.findNext('th')
        if y2 != None:
            print ('y2',y2)
            y3 = y2.find('b')
            if y3 != None:
                y = y3.get_text().encode("utf-8")
                print(y)
    outfile.write(str(x)+"\t"+str(y)+"\n")
    outfile.close()
```

and i got stick here, since it was showing an error like this :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Product/hihello.py", line 4, in 
> contents = f.read()   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
> line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
> 141618: character maps to

So my html file look like this [Report.html](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/images/report_passed.html#total_all) , and is stored in local folder . I have to create excel file out of the table which contain pass or fail .

Comment: Can you add full traceback of the error in the question.

Comment: yeah i added it @Md.NahidurRahman

Comment: According to the error message, it is because your file contains characters other than UTF-8. However, if you want to read the test results of the robot framework, you should take it from file output.xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
#file available in google colab, Importing the required modules
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
#xyz.html available in google colab
path = '/content/xyz.html'

# empty list
data = []

# for getting the header from
# the HTML file
list_header = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path),'html.parser')

header = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'id':'summaryTable','class':'lined'})[0].find("tr")

for items in header:
    try:
        list_header.append(items.get_text().replace('\xa0',' '))
    except:
        continue

# for getting the data
HTML_data = soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all("tr",attrs={'class':' vulnerable'})[:]

for element in HTML_data:
    sub_data = []
    for sub_element in element:
  
        try:
            sub_data.append(sub_element.get_text())
        except:
            continue
    data.append(sub_data)

# Storing the data into Pandas
# DataFrame
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = list_header)

# Converting Pandas DataFrame
# into CSV file
dataFrame.to_csv('htmltabletocsv.csv')
```

Comment: Please provide some description of your solution. At least, describe the achieved code logic.